# Decipher BASIC script

Tags: basic

I've inherited a BASIC script, and I'm trying to rewrite it into Python.  I don't know BASIC, or even which version of BASIC this is.  Is it Visual Basic?  Please help me translate this block of code.

```
'County Number, District Number, District Name 
j = 0
OPEN "" + year.base$ + "dist.csv" FOR INPUT AS #1
INPUT #1, a0$, a1$, a2$, a3$, a4$, a5$, a6$, a7$  
DO WHILE NOT EOF(1)  
j = j + 1  
  INPUT #1, a0$, a1$, a2$, a3$, a4$, a5$, a6$, a7$  
  conumbind(j) = VAL(a0$)  
  distnumbind(j) = VAL(a1$)  
  distnameind$(j) = a2$  
  rate2(j) = VAL(a3$)  
  rate34(j) = rate2(j) * 2  
LOOP  
CLOSE #1  
iTotal2 = j
```

Comment: I'm mainly having trouble with the lines that begin with 'INPUT'.  What are the $ symbols for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello this is QBASIC a DOS based language.
[QBasic on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic)
What this code does is to open a text file, in this case a comma separated values files. Each INPUT #1 sentence will fetch one line of the file and assign the values to the string variables (the ones that end in $ character are string variables). Then it will fill some unidimensional arrays with those values. 
iTotal2 will be the number of records in the file.
The code does practically nothing, since once the arrays are filled, they are not used.

Comment: Thank you.  I think my biggest problem was that I didn't know that it was QBASIC, making it even harder to find answers on my own.  I only posted part of the script. There is some more code that writes the arrays to a new file.  I think I will be able to figure the rest out.

Answer (score 4):

Initialize counter.

```
j = 0
```

Open file for reading.

```
OPEN "" + year.base$ + "dist.csv" FOR INPUT AS #1
```

Read in the first line into 8 variables. These aren't used. I assume they are the header.

```
INPUT #1, a0$, a1$, a2$, a3$, a4$, a5$, a6$, a7$
```

Iterate through the rest of the file.

```
DO WHILE NOT EOF(1)
```

Increment the counter.

```
  j = j + 1
```

Read the next line of the file into 8 variables.

```
  INPUT #1, a0$, a1$, a2$, a3$, a4$, a5$, a6$, a7$
```

Assign the some of the fields to array elements (the VAL function converts to a numeric value).

```
  conumbind(j) = VAL(a0$)  
  distnumbind(j) = VAL(a1$)
  distnameind$(j) = a2$  
  rate2(j) = VAL(a3$)  
  rate34(j) = rate2(j) * 2
```

Finish the loop.

```
LOOP
```

Close the input file.

```
CLOSE #1
```

Save the record count.

```
iTotal2 = j
```